# Postfix dovecot SASL smtp auth

Tags: authentication, smtp, postfix-mta, sasl, dovecot

I configured my email server following the tutorial https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixDovecotSASL

Now when I 
telnet myserver.com 25
ehlo localhost

the output is

250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN

=====
According tutorial ,"250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN ,50-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN" lines mean I config myserver right .
But I still sent the email without auth login .

It is weird .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like ekini says, look in your main.cf configuration file and see if mynetworks parameter is set to localhost (or 127.0.0.0/8 for instance), which is usually the case when this happens.

```
 mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
```

Also this shuld be set to yes:

```
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
```

Try connecting from somewhere else instead...

Answer (score 1):

You can send mail without auth if you have your subnet declared in

$sudo postconf mynetworks