# postfix with sasl authentication not working

Tags: smtp, postfix-mta, sasl

I have a smtp server with postfix with which i m able to send and receive mails.

The problem is when i m connecting from remote client i do not have to supply a valid password. I m able to send mail with any password.

I have tried everything but to no avail.

The output of postconf -n writes -

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mailbox_command =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = example.com, mail.example.com, localhost.example.com, localhost
myhostname = mail.example.com
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relayhost =
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = may
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = cyrus
smtpd_sender_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/cacert.pem
smtpd_tls_auth_only = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/smtpd.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/smtpd.key
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
```

doing a telnet on locahost 25 says -

```
Trying ::1...
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.example.com ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo localhost
250-mail.example.com
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

Any solution?

thanks

Comment: Can you post the complete `SMTP` transaction that succeeded from a remote client using `telnet`?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674701/postfix-dovecot-sasl-smtp-auth and is that answer what you need(ed)?